# CSS gradient comes down as layers

Tags: html, css, gradient

So here's my issue, I'm trying to get this effect

[image]

So I'd use this CSS

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #5FC7F4),
    color-stop(1, #069ADA)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5FC7F4 0%, #069ADA 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #5FC7F4 0%, #069ADA 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5FC7F4 0%, #069ADA 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5FC7F4 0%, #069ADA 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5FC7F4 0%, #069ADA 100%);
```

Now what happens is when I use that, I get

[image]

As you can see there are "layers", and its not exactly a "smooth" gradient. Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/U4FU3/

And ideas?

Comment: It's because your body is empty! If you give it a height or add some content the gradient will stretch. Add `html, body { height: 100%; }` to make it stretch to the full browser height for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with your gradient - you just need to set the height like so:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#gradient {
height: 200px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5FC7F4, #069ADA ); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5FC7F4, #069ADA ); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5FC7F4, #069ADA ); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#5FC7F4, #069ADA); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

This seems to work fine

Check out this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_gradient-linear